# Opensearch - Searching multiple indices - how are the results scored?

Tags: opensearch

We have several different indices in Opensearch, each corresponding to distinct types the user can create in the system.
For example we have "Applications", "Sheets", "Documents" etc.

The types share common fields, ex. "Name" and "Description", but will have many fields that are unique to the types and might be relevant to search.

We can search these indices individually and get the results ranked by relevance.
But really, what would be interesting to the user would be a unified search across these domains.

I can create an alias for all of these indices, and perform one search. It does look to me however, that results from some indices are always ranked highest in score and there can be quite a large discrepancy between the indices even if they are in the same result.

- How does the relevance score calculation now work when searching multiple indices?
- Is there documentation availible for this kind of setup?
- An alternative could be "multi-search" - but is it possible to merge-sort on score?
- What kinds of pitfalls might I encounter, and is there a recommended approach?

Edit: Adding `?searchType=dfs_query_then_fetch` to they search makes it behave more like I expect. Still, Is it possible to merge results from different indexes based on score?